# Head-coupled/Off-axis perspective in Three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, perspective

I'm trying to achieve a permanent head-coupled perspective without using the full headtrackr library. My head won't be moving, but it won't be directly in front of the screen.

I have a little [demo](https://github.com/DBraun/HeadCoupledPerspective) that you can download and run with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

The code is adapted from mainly [this headtrackr example](http://auduno.github.io/headtrackr/examples/sprites_canvas.html) and part of [the headtrackr source](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/blob/master/src/controllers.js)

My expectations are based off this [diagram](https://dev.opera.com/articles/head-tracking-with-webrtc/):[image]

In the third image, I imagine slightly swiveling my monitor counter-clockwise from above. This should be equivalent to reducing Z and making X less than zero. I expect my monitor to show the middle image, but instead I see something like this:
[image]

I think the "window" I'm looking through is the XY-plane, but shouldn't it stretch like the middle orange rectangle in the first diagram? Here's another window that stays fixed: http://kode80.com/2012/04/09/holotoy-perspective-in-webgl/ to see what I mean by "window."

Are off-axis perspective and head-tracking unrelated? How do I get a convincing illusion of off-axis perspective in THREE.js?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish what you're aiming for with `setViewOffset`. Your diagram looks a little off to me. Perhaps its because there is no qube in the off-axis projection, but I think the point is that  the frustum should remain framed on a fixed point without rotating the camera which would introducer perspective distortion.

To accomplish this with `setViewOffset` I would set the `fullWidth` and `fullHeight` to some extra large size. The view offset the will be a window in that oversized view. As the user moves that window will be offset in the opposite direction of the viewer.

http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Cameras/PerspectiveCamera

Answer (score 0):

3D Projection mapping can be broken into a corner-pinning texture step and a perspective adjustment step. I think they're somewhat unrelated.

In Three.js you can make a quad surface (composed of two triangle Face3) and map a texture onto the surface. Then move the corners of the quad in XY (not Z). I don't think this step introduces perspective artifacts other than what's necessary for minor deformations in a quad texture. I think I'm talking about banding issues and nearest neighbor artifacts, not 3d perspective errors. The size of these artifacts depends on how the projector is shining on the object. If the projector is nicely perpendicular to the surface, very little corner-mapping is necessary. If you're using a monitor instead of a projector, then no corner-pinning is necessary.

Next is the perspective adjustment step. You have to adjust the content of the texture based on where the user is in relation to the real-life surface. I believe you can do this with an XYZ distance from the physical viewer to the center of the screen surface, a scaling factor between pixels and real-life size, and the pixel dimensions of the surface.

In my demo, the blueish faces of my cubes point in the positive Z direction. When I rotate my monitor in the real-life world, they continue to point in the positive Z direction of their monitor world. The diagram that I posted is a little misleading because the orange box in the middle picture is locally rotated to compensate for the rotating of the real-life monitor world. That orange box's front face is no longer pointing exactly in the positive Z direction of its monitor world.

Outside of Three.js, in Processing there are some techniques for projection mapping.

This one may be the simplest, although I haven't tried it myself: http://blogs.bl0rg.net/netzstaub/2008/08/24/wiimote-headtracking-in-processing/

SurfaceMapper for Processing has support for real-life curved surfaces (not just flat rectangles), but it only works for Processing before Processing 2.0.

If anyone develops a SurfaceMapper library for Three.js that would be really cool! I'd love to design a virtual world, put cameras in the world, have each camera consider real-life viewer perspective, and then put those rendered textures on real-life displays.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what "corner-pinning", but if you mean to render the default projectionMatrix/frustrum, and then deform the texture, you will run into quite a bit of trouble. First off i don't think that two triangles will cut it, you would have to tesselate this surface. Second, why stretch the image / do extra work etc. when it can simply be achieved with adjusting a matrix. The link has the code, -left + offset right + offset.

Comment: I agree. As you say, there's no need to render to a texture and then deform the texture. For best quality, the corner pinning should be done through a projection matrix without any final texture pass.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the perspective matrix. It's built with -left +right -bottom +top. Changing these will produce the effect you are looking for.

Comment: That is not how the perspective matrix is defined.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean with your comment? It's possible that 5 years ago matrices were defined differently.

Comment: I am sorry for the short comment and fast downvote. It was not very polite. Orthographic projection needs left,right,bottom,top,NEAR,FAR. That specification does not make much sense for perspective projection. Centered perspective can be defined with four parameters FOV,aspect,near,far. If it is offset from the center, it needs at least two more parameters than that. Modern THREE.js has a PerspectiveCamera method setViewOffset ( fullWidth : Float, fullHeight : Float, x : Float, y : Float, width : Float, height : Float ) : null. I will gladly remove the downvote if you correct your answer. :-)

Comment: Granted it may not be valid anymore, but what i was referring to is the "basic" openGL perspective projection matrix. https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/opengl-perspective-projection-matrix. In the literature, left right, top bottom are being mentioned. In threejs world this is derived from things like FOV or aspect ratio, but it still has to map to left,right,top,bottom along with near and far.

Comment: I would argue that this answer is still valid, since internally three.js still uses left, right, top and bottom. `It's built with...` is thus not invalid.  https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js#L195

Also, "adjusting" the perspective matrix NEEDS to happen, regardless of whether you are using the API or directly manipulating it. So that statement is valid as well. While it may not be the best quality answer, nor the best answer (much easier to use the API) i think the better thing to do would be to post your own or upvote the first answer here :)

Comment: It looks like you are right and I am wrong. (And the worst is that I don't fully understand why. ;-) I mean, why no extra parameters are required to shift the focal point wrt. the center of the screen.) My downvote was indeed rushed. Sorry again. I would remove it if I could.

Comment: Now I do, sort of, understand why no extra parameters are needed for offsetting if left,right,top,bottom are defined. The reason, for anyone interested, is that the projection is applied in view space, which is centered on zero.

Comment: Again, I would really like to remove the unfair downvote, but first the answer must be edited. (For instance, moving relevant parts of the comments into the post.) I know I can propose an edit, but I don't want to "steal" your answer.